# Javascript Pass value to another JS Class and HTML Page

Tags: javascript, html

I have two `JavaScript` classes/files, and two `html` pages:

```
-month.html
-month.js
-day.html
-day.js
```

I am trying to figure out how to pass a value from one `html/js` to the other.  For instance, when a user clicks on a date in the `month.html`, I would like to pass that value from `month.js` to `day.js` and then display it on the `day.html`.  Is there a quick way that I can just pass a date to the day.html and then work with it in `day.js`?

Thanks!

Comment: at least 3: url parameters, cookies, localstorage

Comment: one more to add you can carry session data..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using a cookie or localStorage for this purpose.

If using localStorage in month.js do:

```
localStorage.setItem('date', date);
```

and in day.js retrieve the date with:

```
var date = localStorage.getItem('date');
```

Keep in mind, that localStorage is not supported in older browsers. You can read more about alternative local storage methods here: http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html